# Pass value to Ionic v1 app from a Java Function

Tags: java, android, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-v1

As a workaround for a hardware bug in an Android based POS device, I have to use following Java code to capture the NFC Tag Id. Each and every time the device get a NFC input, this Java code can capture its Tag Id and it will be assigned to `nfcTagId` inside the switch statement.

I want to pass this `nfcTagId` to my Ionic v1 app as soon as the device got hit with a NFC card, and start a broadcast function to invoke other methods. What is the best way to archive this?

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final Pattern KEYCODE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("KEYCODE_(\\w)");
    String id = "";
    String nfcTagId = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:


                nfcTagId = id;
                return true;

            default:
                String key = KeyEvent.keyCodeToString(keyCode);

                Matcher matcher = KEYCODE_PATTERN.matcher(key);
                if (matcher.matches()) {

                    id += matcher.group(1);
                }

                return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
        }

    }

}
```